# Exponential decay to a line with slope

Tags: exponential-function

I have a question about exponential decay. Suppose I have an exponential decay at point $(x,y)$. Instead of decaying to $x-$axis, I want to decay it to a line with slope $(s')$. I also want the decay line to match slope $(s)$ and curvature $(c)$ at point $(x,y)$. Can anyone please show me how to solve this problem? Thanks

Comment: I can't quite see what you want. It would help if you can [edit] your question to show us a picture of what you want.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange! A quick [tour](https://math.stackexchange.com/tour) will enhance your experience. Here are helpful tips to [write a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/9960#9960) and [write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).  For equations, please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Answer (score 1):

Here's my take on this.

Exponential decay is
$y = ae^{-bx}$.

A line is
$y = ux+v$.

So,
exponential decay to the line is
$y
=ae^{bx}+ux+v$.

From what you say,
$u = s'$.

Since no intercept is specified,
I will assume that
$v = 0$.

Therefore the equation is
$y
=ae^{-bx}+s'x
$.

The slope is
$y'
=-abe^{-bx}+s'
$.

If the slope is
$s$ at $x$,
then
$s
=-abe^{-bx}+s'
$.
This is an equation
involving $a$ and $b$.

The curvature is
$\kappa
=\dfrac{x'y''-y'x''}{(x'^2+y'^2)^{3/2}}
=\dfrac{y''}{(1+y'^2)^{3/2}}
$.

For this curve,
$y''
=ab^2e^{-bx}
$,
so
$\kappa
=\dfrac{ab^2e^{-bx}}{1+(-abe^{-bx}+s')^2)^{3/2}}
=c
$.

This is a second equation
for $a$ and $b$
involving
$x, y, s', $ and $c$.

Solve these for $a$ and $b$.